# Non-uniform scale of page size

Tags: beamer, paper-size, pgfpages

I have a beamer talk to be presented. The screen is 16:9, but the system is set up in such a way that 4:3 information is sent to the projector and then non-uniformly scaled to 16:9, causing, of course, very bad and ugly effects. However, I'm not allowed/able to change it.

Therefore I would like to prepare PDF slides in such a way that I make 16:9 slides and stretch them in one direction to fit in 4:3 page. I tried to understand the `pgfpages` manual and it seems that there's a `xscale` option, which is probably what I look for. However, it is an argument to `\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions` which doesn't make any sense to me.

So, how can I make the following MWE output slides like the one below?

*Remark 1: The correct value is `xscale=(4:3)/(16:9)=0.75`.*

*Remark 2: Post-processing the PDF file by an external application is an option, too. However, it should keep the vector structure of the file and not convert it to a bitmap (like `convert` from ImageMagick does).*

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
% what to put here?

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{16:9 to 4:3}

\Huge A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R

\centerline{a square $\rightarrow$ \rule{2cm}{2cm} $\leftarrow$ or not?}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One woudl have to know how the projector works.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well, will a 30-page talk, I think I would prefer to have a bad talk than to learn a very new thing the night before the talk :) As well, `pgfpages` are independent of `beamer`. What is `texpower` about?

Comment: Please ignore my first remark.  You need to do this in two stages: first create the pdf 16x9, then convert to 4x3.

Comment: It appears that pdfpages ALWAYS preserves the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you can get pdfpages to change the aspect ratio after all.  The original 16x9 document was stored in file test.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,height=4.5in,width=6in,fitpaper=true]{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer]